# HoloEverywhere overrides ActionBarSherlock's Theme.Sherlock

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

This kind of bug is like a black magic :

I am trying to port https://github.com/SimonVT/android-timepicker to complete Holo style (by default it has got only ICS timepicker widget, dialog remains pre-Honeycomb).

I have extended Theme.Sherlock with timepicker's special attributes , then applied it to whole application. Dialog looks the same as in default ( mentioned above). After that I just added HoloEverywhere lib to project ... BLACK magic appears! Timepicker widget somehow lost some of it's views like blue lines and changed position within dialog. I am still wondering about reason of this glitch.

Note : in my project(code) as well as in TimePicker lib I have got absolutely nothing concerning HoloEverywhere

Note: I also changed some attributes in timepicker because they are conflicting with HoloEverywhere's attributes (because of "... attribute has already been declared" error)

Code:

```
public class DialogSample extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnTimeSetListener {

    private TextView mTimeDisplay;

    private int mHour;
    private int mMinute;

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);

        findViewById(R.id.btnDialog).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");    
            }
        });

        updateDisplay();
    }

    // updates the time we display in the TextView
    private void updateDisplay() {
        mTimeDisplay.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                        .append(pad(mHour)).append(":")
                        .append(pad(mMinute)));
    }

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10) {
            return String.valueOf(c);
        } else {
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
        }
    }






    static public class TimePickerFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {

        @Override
        public TimePickerDialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


            return new TimePickerDialog(getSherlockActivity(), (DialogSample)getSherlockActivity(), hour, minute, true);
        }

        public TimePickerFragment() {

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
         mHour = hourOfDay;
         mMinute = minute;
         updateDisplay();

    }
}
```

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-timepicker

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is tricky : I added HoloEverywhere to

1) NumberPicker lib
2) TimePicker lib
3) TimePicker dialog lib
4) to my project

but I am still not satisfied with this because  solution is the same way unclear as an issue

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want holo style time picker and number picker. You can use  [holoeverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) components you don't need SimonVT

Comment: I simply prefer dialog of ICS rather than of JellyBean that is ported in HoloEverywhere. This is the reason I am porting standalone dialog